# Display full content on search result - twenty fourteen theme

Tags: wordpress, themes

I am using the twenty fourteen theme. I want to display the full content of the posts on the search result page, not just the excerpt of the posts.

Please give me the solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In content.php file you will see this piece of code:

```
<?php if ( is_search() ) : ?>
<div class="entry-summary">
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</div><!-- .entry-summary -->
<?php else : ?>
<div class="entry-content">
    <?php
        /* translators: %s: Name of current post */
        the_content( sprintf(
            __( 'Continue reading %s <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentyfourteen' ),
            the_title( '<span class="screen-reader-text">', '</span>', false )
        ) );

        wp_link_pages( array(
            'before'      => '<div class="page-links"><span class="page-links-title">' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentyfourteen' ) . '</span>',
            'after'       => '</div>',
            'link_before' => '<span>',
            'link_after'  => '</span>',
        ) );
    ?>
</div><!-- .entry-content -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

You will need to display the_content instead of the_excerpt on the third line. You can simply replace the_excerpt functions with the_content but you might end up with not so beautiful styling so you will need to wrap it into appropriate html, for example like this:

```
<?php if ( is_search() ) : ?>
<div class="entry-content">
    <?php the_content( sprintf(
            __( 'Continue reading %s <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentyfourteen' ),
            the_title( '<span class="screen-reader-text">', '</span>', false )
        ) ); ?>
</div><!-- .entry-summary -->
<?php else : ?>
<div class="entry-content">
    <?php
        /* translators: %s: Name of current post */
        the_content( sprintf(
            __( 'Continue reading %s <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentyfourteen' ),
            the_title( '<span class="screen-reader-text">', '</span>', false )
        ) );

        wp_link_pages( array(
            'before'      => '<div class="page-links"><span class="page-links-title">' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentyfourteen' ) . '</span>',
            'after'       => '</div>',
            'link_before' => '<span>',
            'link_after'  => '</span>',
        ) );
    ?>
</div><!-- .entry-content -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I want to put this function in a plugin, how do I write the code ? Thanks

Comment: Hello Nick,

I have tested your code and it worked. Is it possible to write plugin for this ?

Comment: For this kind of thing child theme would be more appropriate than plugin.